# Adding all cpp files name in a single variable in batch file

Tags: batch-file

So I am using g++ and want to make a .bat file that takes all the .cpp in my folder to compile them.
The problem is that I can't get my variable holding the file name to hold the other file names found.
I have this for now:

```
set objs=
for /R %%f in (*.cpp) do set objs=!objs! %%f
set cc=C:\MinGW\bin/g++.exe
set include_paths=-IF:\SDL_Files\SDL2-2.0.4-mingw\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2 -IF:\SDL_Files\SDL2_image-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\include\SDL2
set library_paths=-LF:\SDL_Files\SDL2-2.0.4-mingw\i686-w64-mingw32\lib -LF:\SDL_Files\SDL2_image-2.0.1\i686-w64-mingw32\lib
set compiler_flags=-w -Wl,-subsystem,windows -fno-exceptions
set linker_flags=-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
set obj_name=bullshit
@echo on
%cc% %objs% %include_paths% %library_paths% %compiler_flags% %linker_flags% -o %obj_name%

pause
```

Im not missing much but it's blocking me and I can't find the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set objs=
for /R %%f in (*.cpp) do call set objs=%%objs%% %%f
```

Without the call the for loop just overwrites %obj% rather than appending to it.

%%objs%% is needed as %% is interpretted as % when pass to call (%% is an escaped % character)